# Cannot modify language field in node form using hook_form_alter in drupal 7

Tags: i18n-l10n, forms

I tried adding a description for the language field in a node form using hook_form_alter:

```
$form['language']['#description'] = t('Description');
```

The changes are not accepted, the language field stays as it is the description is not added. As far as i can tell this is not a problem with the hook, because changes to other fields work fine, only the language field does not change.
Any ideas what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Have you dumped the contents of $form to see if you are getting the correct element?

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because the node edit/create form sets `$form['language']` using the following code. (See [node_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.pages.inc/function/node_form/7).)

```
  // Basic node information.
  // These elements are just values so they are not even sent to the client.
  foreach (array('nid', 'vid', 'uid', 'created', 'type', 'language') as $key) {
    $form[$key] = array(
      '#type' => 'value', 
      '#value' => isset($node->$key) ? $node->$key : NULL,
    );
  }
```

It's then the Locale module that changes the form field in [locale_form_node_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!locale!locale.module/function/locale_form_node_form_alter/7) using the following code.

```
  if (isset($form['#node']->type) && locale_multilingual_node_type($form['#node']->type)) {
    $form['language'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select', 
      '#title' => t('Language'), 
      '#default_value' => (isset($form['#node']->language) ? $form['#node']->language : ''), 
      '#options' => array(LANGUAGE_NONE => t('Language neutral')) + locale_language_list('name'),
    );
  }
  // Node type without language selector: assign the default for new nodes
  elseif (!isset($form['#node']->nid)) {
    $default = language_default();
    $form['language'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value', 
      '#value' => $default->language,
    );
  }
```

If your module is executed before the Locale module, its changes to the language form field are not retained, as the Locale module set `$form['language']` to a different array.

In order for your code to work, you need to change the weight of your module, or implement [hook_module_implements_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7) to alter the order hooks are executed.

```
function mymodule_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'form_alter') {
    // Move mymodule_form_alter() to the end of the list. module_implements()
    // iterates through $implementations with a foreach loop which PHP iterates
    // in the order that the items were added, so to move an item to the end of
    // the array, we remove it and then add it.
    $group = $implementations['mymodule'];
    unset($implementations['mymodule']);
    $implementations['mymodule'] = $group;
  }
}
```

This code changes also the order in which `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`, and `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()` are executed.

Answer (score 1):

@kiamlaluno: I don't think your approach works. Here a comment from the i18n module:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
 function i18n_node_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
 $node = $form['#node'];
 /**
  * i18n has to override locale.module
  * drupal_alter() fails to order modules correctly in some cases
  * for example specific hooks like hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter
  *
  * its not possbile to reorder hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter with
  * hook_module_implements_alter
  *
  * @see http://drupal.org/node/765860
  */

   // call a 'private' implemenation of i18n_node_form_node_form_alter()
   $form['#after_build'][] = '_i18n_node_form_node_form_alter';
  }
```

I used the '#pre_render' property to solve this:

```
  function your_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state){
    $form['language']['#pre_render'][] = '_your_module_language_node_prerender';
   }

   function _your_module_language_node_prerender($element){
     // do something with $element
     return $element
   }
```